# Excel VBA Loop Range and skip blank

Tags: vba, excel

I have below vba code to loop thru range in cell L26 and below, is it working fine but i would like to skip if the cell is blank, i have googled and found this code:

```
For i = 10 To 49 
    Cells(i, 4).Select 
    If Cells(i, 4).Value <> "" Then 
        code.... 
    End If
```

How to modify above code into my vba code below, would appreciate your advise and help, thank you.

```
Sub PLANNER()

Dim loopRng As Range
Dim r As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each r In Sheet7.Range("L26", Range("L" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    Sheet7.Range("L19").Value = r.Value
    Set loopRng = Worksheets("setting").Range("L21")
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = loopRng
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Call planner_Mail
Next r
Sheet2.Range("D2").Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my code below, explanation (and some questions) in the code's comments:

```
Option Explicit

Sub PLANNER()

Dim loopRng As Range
Dim R As Range
Dim Sht As Worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set Sht = Sheet7 ' <-- make sure this is the worksheet you have your data
With Sht
    For Each R In .Range("L26", .Range("L" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        If Trim(R.Value) <> "" Then ' check that cell is not blank
            .Range("L19").Value = R.Value
            Set loopRng = Worksheets("setting").Range("L21") ' Not sure if Sheet7 = Worksheets("setting")
            ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = loopRng
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            planner_Mail ' you can "drop" the "Call"
        End If
    Next R
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Bravo! your code is working perfectly, you read my code correctly! This has ended my 10-hour googling and trial and error, thank you so much for your help!!

Answer (score 1):

I think this should do it.

```
Sub PLANNER()
Dim loopRng As Range
Dim r As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  For Each r In Sheet7.Range("L26", Range("L" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
      If r.Value <> "" Then
          Sheet7.Range("L19").Value = r.Value
      End If
  Set loopRng = Worksheets("setting").Range("L21")
 ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = loopRng
 Application.CutCopyMode = False
  Call planner_Mail
Next r

Sheet2.Range("D2").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: hi, thanks for sharing, but the code is not working, it didn't skip blank cells.

Comment: @robin Hm, that should've worked. Are you sure the cells are blank actually blank?

Comment: Hi, yes the cell is blank, i am changing the code here and there, still not working. eg. i have 10 cells in range, eg. L26 to L35, in between there are some  blank cells, the code just repeated last one till the last at L35, not skip if blank.